# check at least two out of ten booleans are true

Tags: language-agnostic, logic, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

In a case where at least two out of three booleans are true, this is the easiest way to find out:

```
BOOL a, b, c;
-(BOOL)checkAtLeastTwo
{
  return a && (b || c) || (b && c); 
}
```

What will be the optimal solution if there is ten booleans and at least two of them needs to be true? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original implementation is sub-optimal - you can just sum true values:

```
return (int)a + (int)b + (int)c >= 2;
```

Obviously you can extend this to 10 variables:

```
return (int)a + (int)b + (int)c + (int)d + (int)e +
       (int)f + (int)g + (int)h + (int)i + (int)j >= 2;
```

Comment: This works assuming the language in question promotes boolean true to the integer value 1 - I think this is true for most common modern languages, but it's worth pointing out this assumption. I seem to remember at least one language where boolean true promoted to an all 1s bit pattern, so this obviously would not work in that case (can't put my finger on what language it was at the moment, and it may not have even been a "real" one, but an academic toy or something...). Even if that's the case, you could rewrite this pattern using conditionals or something...

Comment: @twalberg, yes of course... But I think in that case it shoudn't be ahrd to write your own conversion method in any language :)

Comment: Yes - this is true for all C-like languages (and quite a few more besides), and the OP is apparently using Objective-C. But for a language where true is not equal to 1 the same general approach should still be viable, with some adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

In C you can just check sum of your variables

```
return a + b + .... + n >= 2;
```

If implicit conversion from boolean to integer doesn't in your language, you can simply convert your variables to integer and check sum of converted values.